# If H(m) = 0 for some m, how can a DSA signature be forged?

Tags: hash, public-key, dsa

If we know for some message $m$ that $H(m) = 0$, how can we forge a DSA signature with only the public key?

I got that $g^s*r = (g^x)^r$ where $x$ is the private key, but that's one equation with 2 unknowns, and since discrete log is hard, I can't substitute a value for either $s$ or $r$ and find the other and satisfying the condition $0 < s$ and $r < q$ at the same time.

Comment: @24601 Your current approach does not really help you. Look what happens to $u_1$ if $H(m)$ happens to be zero and how the verification equation simplifies. Now, take a closer look at the right hand side of the verification equation. Could the choice of $s$ help you? ;) I used the notation from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Signature_Algorithm).

Comment: As DrLecter says, when asking this sort of question, please make sure to describe what you've tried and where you got stuck.  We expect you to make a serious effort before asking here and to show us what you've tried and where you got stuck.

Comment: @24601 correct. But that's only one choice for $r$ ;) You can exponentiate your choice of $r$ with an arbitrary value $a$ (other than $1$) from $Z_q$ as long as you also put it's inverse in $s$.

Comment: @DrLecter, would you mind officially answering this question so it gets off of our "unanswered questions" statistic?

Answer (score 2):

The signature equation is $$r = (g^{H(m) s^{-1}} y^{r s^{-1}} \bmod p) \bmod q,$$ where $g$ is the standard generator of an order-$q$ subgroup of $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$, $y \in \mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ is a public key, $m$ is a message, and the signature is $(r, s)$ for scalars $r, s \in \mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$.

If $H(m) = 0$, this reduces to $r = (y^{r s^{-1}} \bmod p) \bmod q$.  If you pick $r = s = y \bmod q$, then $r s^{-1} \equiv 1 \pmod q$, so $y^{r s^{-1}} \bmod p = y$ and so $(y^{r s^{-1}} \bmod p) \bmod q = y \bmod q = r$ as desired.